# POST session variables to a relational database with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, session

I am trying to add some data to a relational database, and would like the session_user_id to be the foreign key for that database. When a user clicks a button, I want to make a database entry with the session_user_id and some other information I have POSTed to the page. My ajax posts to the php webpage page which it is run on (meaning all my scripts are on the same page)

I am currently getting a `Uncaught ReferenceError: $sess_user_id1 is not defined`. The jquery is firing. While I would love to get the undefined variable fixed, overall this does not seem like a very direct way to to this, and has added a bunch of confusing variables, when all the variables I need were already in my PHP statement. Is there any way to trigger the PHP entry without going through ajax and having to define the variables again?

Here is my php, which is at the header which is on the same page as my JS and HTML:

```
<?php
    $markerid = $_POST["id"];
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $type = $_POST["type"];
    $point = $_POST["point"];
    $lat2 = $_POST["lat"];
    $lng2 = $_POST["lng"];
    $locationdescription = $_POST["locationdescription"];
    $locationsdirections = $_POST["locationdirections"];

    session_start();
    if (!isset($_SESSION['sess_user_id']) || empty($_SESSION['sess_user_id'])) {
        // redirect to your login page
        exit();
    }

    $sess_user_id1 = $_SESSION['sess_user_id'];

    if ((isset($_POST['usid'])) && (isset($_POST['usid']))) {
        $user_id_follow = strip_tags($_POST['usid']);

        echo $user_id_follow;

        $query = "INSERT INTO markerfollowing ( userID, markerID, type )
            VALUES ('$user_id_follow', '$markerid', '$type');";

        $result = mysql_query($query);

        if (!$result) {
            die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
        }

        mysql_close();
    }
?>
```

Here is the HTML button:

```
<div class="btn pull-right">
    <button class="btn btn-large btn-followmarker" type="submit"id="followmarker">Add me to the list</button>   
</div>
```

Here is the jquery/ajax post:

```
<script/javascript>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#followmarker").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "", // 
                data: { usid: <?php echo '$sess_user_id1'; ?>},
                success: function(msg){
                    alert("success");
                    $("#thanks").html(msg);
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert("failure");
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script
```

A sincere thanks for any and all help. I haven't worked with relational databases before.

Answer (score 0):

`<?php echo '$sess_user_id1'; ?>` 
is wrong. If you wont to get
`data: { usid: 123}` at $sess_user_id1 is **123**, you should write

```
data: { usid: <?php echo "$sess_user_id1"; ?>}
```

See your html source code in your brawser. I think there is `data: { usid: $sess_user_id1}`, and javascript is not understand what is the **$sess_user_id1**

This is the only one problem that I can see now, but I don't understand your current task whole to say more.

Comment: Wow, that worked. Thanks a bunch. I should have tried that earlier (I think I did try it earlier, but had a different bug at that time)

Comment: but still, if anyone knows a way to do this without ajax, and without having to redefine the variables, that would be great to know, and could be helpful to others as well.

Comment: If you need to transfer data from user to server the reality is that you have REQUEST. It can be GET or POST or other. It can be with reload all page or without is (ajax). If you have some reason to avoid requests on some time, you can keep data in some storage but you will need to send your keeped later, this way is more difficult, I do not know such reasons..

Comment: I do not understand that the redefine you mean.